# Maven Surefire not executing test phase

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, groovy, maven-surefire-plugin

When running `mvn test` it appears that surefire is not executing it's test goal (or at the very least is not picking up the tests which I have included within the configuration.

This is a multi-module maven project, currently all in groovy, with a structure similar to the below:

```
root
-commons
-framework
-generatedsources1
-generatedsources2
-test-groups
--test-group1
---src/test/java/path.to.TestClass.groovy
--test-group2
```

I have the follow surefire configuration within the `test-groups` pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <useFile>false</useFile>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Spec.groovy</include>
                    <include>**/*Test.groovy</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However when I execute `mvn test` against this pom.xml, or either of the sub-poms, the test phase is never executed.

This is the maven output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building system-test-category-man 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gmavenplus-plugin:1.6:compile (default) @ system-test-category-man ---
[INFO] Using Groovy 2.4.9 to perform compile.
[INFO] Compiled 2 files.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gmavenplus-plugin:1.6:compileTests (default) @ system-test-category-man ---
[INFO] Using Groovy 2.4.9 to perform compileTests.
[INFO] Compiled 3 files.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.809 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-08T10:53:29Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/175M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And when I call the plugin directly:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building system-test-category-man 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-cli) @ system-test-category-man ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.315 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-08T10:58:18Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Have I misconfigured anything?

Comment: Could you post the full pom ?

Answer (score 1):

The question puzzled me too, but I think I found out what the problem is.

From the perspective of the `maven-surefire-plugin` Groovy classes are nothing but meaningless text files, it cannot scan it for annotations. But instead of specifying Groovy sources, I could successfully specify `<includes>` in terms of class names (this example should pick up *everything*):

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.class</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Otherwise you must name your tests (your Groovy test classes) according to the default naming convention that is documented here: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes and goes like this:

```xml
<includes>
    <include>**/Test*.java</include>
    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
    <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

(mentally replace .java with .groovy here)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the workingDirectory:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>wherever you have your tests</workingDirectory>
                <useFile>false</useFile>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Spec.groovy</include>
                    <include>**/*Test.groovy</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**UPDATED 11/01/2018:** 
Not sure that would solve the issue, but can you try to add those dependencies as reporting ones (outside the build dependencies):

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <showSuccess>true</showSuccess>
                <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: Garcia, yes I have, it produces the same result.

Comment: Try also with <include>/**/*Spec.groovy</include>. Note the starting /

Comment: Same thing unfortunately - what's really irritating is that there appears to be no reference to surefire:test in the debug.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you please check it as well?